# Efficiently find an element in multiple sorted lists?

Tags: java, algorithm

**Problem Statement:-**

I was ask this interview question recently.. I was able to come up with the below code only which runs in O(k log n)-

Given k <= n sorted arrays each of size n, there exists a data structure requiring O(kn) preprocessing time and memory that answers iterated search queries in O(k + log n) time.

I have k sorted Lists, each of size n. Currently I have hard coded 5 sorted Lists each of size 3 but in general that can be very high number-

I would like to search for single element in each of the k Lists.

Obviously, I can binary search each array individually, which will result in O(k log n) where k is number of sorted arrays.

Can we do it in O(k + log n) where k is the number of sorted arrays? As I think there might be some better way of doing it as we're doing the same searches k times as of now -

```
private List<List<Integer>> dataInput;

public SearchItem(final List<List<Integer>> inputs) {
    dataInput = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    for (List<Integer> input : inputs) {
        dataInput.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(input));
    }
}

public List<Integer> getItem(final Integer x) {
    List<Integer> outputs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (List<Integer> data : dataInput) {
        int i = Collections.binarySearch(data, x); // binary searching the item
        if (i < 0)
            i = -(i + 1);
        outputs.add(i == data.size() ? null : data.get(i));
    }
    return outputs;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<Integer>> lists = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(3, 4, 6));
    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
    List<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(2, 3, 6));
    List<Integer> list4 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
    List<Integer> list5 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(4, 8, 13));

    lists.add(list1);
    lists.add(list2);
    lists.add(list3);
    lists.add(list4);
    lists.add(list5);

    SearchItem search = new SearchItem(lists);
    System.out.println(dataInput);

    List<Integer> dataOuput = search.getItem(5);

    System.out.println(dataOuput);
}
```

Whatever output I am seeing with my above code approach should come with the new approach as well which should work in `O(k + log n)`.

Is this possible to achieve? Can anyone provide an example how would this work basis on my example?

Comment: What is an iterated search query?  Never heard that term...

Comment: Maybe merging the lists together as a pre-processing step, and then doing a binary search on the merged list?

Comment: Whatever approach I am doing currently in the code is called the iterated search query I guess? Not sure..

Comment: @ksun Won't work. Merging is O(kn), but then searching is O(kn log kn), which is more than the given bound.

Comment: @Gene Searching is O(log kn), or O(log k + log n) per search.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Right. Sorry. Typing faster than thinking.  The problem is merge is not O(kn) but O(kn log k).  You could create an index of size n into the list of kn items.  Do binary search on the index, then within the block of k items. But the preprocessing is too long!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Not really. Let's say `list1 = [0,..,n], list2 = [n,...,n] and list3 = [n,...,2*n]`. When merging you can get the list `list1 + list2 + list3`. If you now search for the element `n`, the results for list1 and list3 are `n` elements apart, so how do you find those in `O(log n)`? You could compress all the `n`s into a single node, but you still can't answer predecessor/successor queries (which wasn't explicitely asked here but happens to be possible efficiently as well).

Comment: @NiklasB I would search the index twice: once looking for the block of k (sorted) elements that has its initial value <= to the search key and again to find the block that ends with a value > than the search key.  Then I'd search these 2 blocks to find the places where the n's start and stop.  Twice as much work as if you assume no duplicates, but still O(n + k)

Comment: @Gene: "Then I'd search these 2 blocks to find the places" But the range of your search value could have size `ω(log n)` and you don't know where the different lists are within the range

Comment: @Gene I thought the question stated that there could be a preprocessing step of O(kn) and after that step the searches need to be below O(k + log n), which as dashblinkenlight pointed out would be O(log kn).

Comment: @ksun: Yeah, but how would you merge `k` lists in `O(kn)`?

Comment: @ksun: Also, using classical binary search you can not only find the position of an element in a sorted sequence but also its successor/predecessor if the element is not in the sequence. You lose that ability if you create one big, merged sequence because then there can be `ω(log n)` elements between the point where your binary search brings you and the results of the search for some of the lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The technique is called [Fractional cascading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_cascading) which sounds very cool. What you do is the following:

1. Take list 1. Take every second element of it and merge it into list 2. Now "the new" list 2 contains all its elements and half of the ones from list 1. 
   You remember which ones are from list 1 and pointers back to list 1 and then you pass through the newly created list 2 from front to back, adding for every element a pointer to the last element from list 1 that you saw and to the last element from list 2 that you saw. Do the same from back to front.
2. Take the "new" list 2 with half of list 1's elements embedded and merge it with list 3 etc.

The resulting interleaving will look something like this:

[image: fractional cascading]

(Source: ["You could have invented fractional cascading" by Edward Z. Yang](http://blog.ezyang.com/2012/03/you-could-have-invented-fractional-cascading/))

and every list element will have a couple of pointers to find predecessors/successors of a certain kind fast and to find the position in the list `i - 1`.

Turns out the total number of list elements is only increased by a constant factor, but the cool thing is that you can now do queries fast:

1. Do a binary search in "new" list k to find your search element. Complexity: `O(log n)`. You now found the element in the original list k, because you can find in O(1) the surrounding elements that were originally in list k.
2. You can also find the position of the element in list k - 1 in `O(1)` because you have pointers to the successor/predecessor in list k - 1. So you can report the result for all the other lists in `O(1)` each

Total runtime: `O(log n + k)`

For more information, you should definitely read the [blog post](http://blog.ezyang.com/2012/03/you-could-have-invented-fractional-cascading/), it has lots of visualizing illustrations and additional explanations.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.. never heard of that before.. Can you provide a simple example for me basis on my code as this is looking slightly complicated.. By that I will be able to understand much better..

Comment: @SSH: Yes it is slightly complicated. It's not a simple change, so I can't show you with your own code. It's probably 50 lines or more to implement

Comment: From your answer.. Yes it is looking complicated :) but somehow I am not able to understand how to implement this in my own solution.. It's a little tricky I guess..

Comment: @SSH: You basically need the concept (class?) of a "colored" sorted array with 6 pointers per element. It has two types of elements, red and blue ones (let's say blue are the elements embedded from earlier lists). Every element has pointers to its blue/red predecessors/successors and every blue element has a pointer to its index in the embedded list. You embed an array into another by a merge-like procedure (`O(n)`) and then you preprocess your lists by embedding the lists into each other. The query procedure itself is then reasonably easy to implement

Comment: I don't think this works.  Two adjacent elements in list k can enclose  the _entire_ sorted list k-1. So the pointers do no good. You still have to search all of list k-1, then you might have to search all of k-2 for the same reason, etc. The example in the Wikipedia article is different from this problem.

Comment: @Gene: No that's not possible, since every second element from "new" list `k - 1` is also in "new" list `k` (that's what you did the preprocessing step for). So unless "new" list `k - 1` has less than 3 elements, your statement is wrong.

Comment: By the way, what OP describes is indeed exactly the problem mentioned in the [Example chapter for fractional cascading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_cascading#Example) of Wikipedia, or am I missing something?

Comment: @SSH: I have added a video link that might help you visualize the idea

Comment: @NiklasB. Thanks for the link.. I tried implementing it by seeing the video but after some time, I decided to quit.. :( It is looking too complicated for me to integrate it in my code base..

Comment: @SSH I actually find it hard to believe that someone would be expected to come up with this stuff in an interview

Comment: @NiklasB. From your above comment, now I can understand how complicated it is :) .. And how foolish my interviewer was to expect this at onsite... May be he wanted me to explain the algo after certain point.. not sure yet.. but this question is still in my head..

Comment: Ignore my previous remark about the fractional cascade not working. Now I think I see it.

Comment: By any chance, if anyone can provide me an example basis on my code how would I be integrating this algorithm, then it will be of great help to me.. I know as @Niklas mention it is complicated but for me to understand this, I need to see the algorithm integrated in my example so that I can debug through and see how it works out.. Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: @SSH: I don't think that's true, real source code is usually much more complicated than pseudocode/general concepts. I think it would be much easier to grasp this by pen and paper and a few example arrays. The pointers are so much easier to grasp when drawn as arrows between arrays. [Here is another article](http://blog.ezyang.com/2012/03/you-could-have-invented-fractional-cascading/) that helps understand and visualize the concept. Then you can think about how to implement this yourself

Comment: What I said is especially true for this particular algorithm. It's easy to understand the concept, but the implementation is a bit unpleasant because of all the bookkeeping you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Since your arrays are sorted, the elements are comparable. Using a B-tree structure, and make sure the arrays doesn't have overlapping segments i.e. each array are sorted and any item inside is either

item < first for all the other arrays; or
item > last for all the other arrays.

Then O(k + logn) is achieved by comparing the searching item so that first < search item < last; then do a log(n) search inside.

But essentially this can be O(logk + logn).

Answer (score 0):

Someone else has probably answered this by now (I haven't refreshed the page). But here is a method for merging the list that should work in O(hn). I haven't actually tested the syntax in an editor, but I think the idea should work...

After calling this method you should just be able to do a binary search on the merged list.

```
public static List<Integer> mergeSortedLists(List<List<Integer>> sortedLists){
  List<Integer> mergedList = new List<Integer>();
  int listIndexes[] = new int[sortedLists.size];
  //initialize indexes to 0
  for(int i=0; i<sortedLists.Count(); i++){
    listIndex[i] = 0;
  }  
  int completedLists=0;
  int lowestValue;
  int lowestIndex;
  while(completedLists < sortedLists.Count()){  
    lowestValue = sortedLists[0][listIndexes[0]];
    lowestIndex = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<sortedLists.Count(); i++){      
      int currentIndex = listIndexes[i];      
      List<Integer> currentList = sortedLists[i];
      if(currentIndex >= currentList) continue; //already finished merging this list skip
      int currentValue = currentList[currentIndex];
      if(currentValue < lowestValue){
         lowestValue = currentValue;
         lowestIndex = currentIndex;
      }
    }
    //put the lowest found value into mergedList and increment index
    mergedList.Add(lowestValue);
    listIndexes[lowestIndex]++;
    //if incremented index is equal to increment completed Lists - when all lists are marked
    //complete the while loop will be broken out of and merge should be complete
    if(listIndexes[lowestIndex] == sortedLists[lowestIndex].Count()){
        completedLists++;   
    }
  }
  return mergedList;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... maybe this won't actually work because the merged list doesn't keep track of what list the values are coming from if that's required. Anyway... it was worth a shot...

Comment: I don't think that's `O(kn)`. It looks more like `O(k^2*n)` (the final list will have `k*n` elements and you need `k` iterations to find the minimum). You could get it down to `O(kn * log k)` by using a binary heap to find the minimum in each step.